# Get radare2 to only display assembly code without other info

Tags: radare2

I'm using radare2 in a loop that looks similar to this:

```
for item in `r2 -c "aaaa" -c "afl" -qq 67b79382375cc5169d869dccca033be3786aa06a71b9bc1245cd4b935a603dc2.bin | grep -Eo "fcn.*"`; do r2 -c "e scr.color=0" -c "aaaa" -c "s $item" -c "pdf" -qq 67b79382375cc5169d869dccca033be3786aa06a71b9bc1245cd4b935a603dc2.bin >> results.asm; done
```

What I need to do is get the output from this:

```
┌ 8: fcn.00401000 (int32_t arg_8h);
│           ; arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8
│           0x00401000      55             push ebp                    ; [00] -r-x section size 4096 named .text
│           0x00401001      8bec           mov ebp, esp
│           0x00401003      ff5508         call dword [arg_8h]         ; 8
│           0x00401006      5d             pop ebp
└           0x00401007      c3             ret
```

To just look like this:

```
; 8: fcn.00401000 (int32_t arg_8h);
; arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8
push ebp                    ; [00] -r-x section size 4096 named .text
mov ebp, esp
call dword [arg_8h]         ; 8
pop ebp
ret
```

IS this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pif`:

Output for `main()` using `pif`:

```
[0x00001060]> pif @ main
endbr64
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
lea rdi, str.hello
call sym.imp.puts
mov eax, 0
pop rbp
ret
```

Output for `main()` using `pdf`:

```
[0x00001060]> pdf @ main
            ; DATA XREF from entry0 @ 0x1081(r)
┌ 27: int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
│           0x00001149      f30f1efa       endbr64
│           0x0000114d      55             push rbp
│           0x0000114e      4889e5         mov rbp, rsp
│           0x00001151      488d3dac0e00.  lea rdi, str.hello          ; 0x2004 ; "hello" ; const char *s
│           0x00001158      e8f3feffff     call sym.imp.puts           ; int puts(const char *s)
│           0x0000115d      b800000000     mov eax, 0
│           0x00001162      5d             pop rbp
└           0x00001163      c3             ret
```